# getting the ID or VALUE or NAME from an <a> link with JS

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get the value of some  link with js, but everytime i get the alert: **undefined**.

I have'd try a lot of things but nothing will work for me :( maybe some of your guys can help me???

code:

```
function protected_link() { 

    var pass1 = prompt("Wachtwoord!!!");
    var pass2 = "admin";
    var kerntaak = $(this).attr("id");

if (pass1 === pass2) {
    load('img/pdf/'+kerntaak+'.pdf')

    } else {
        load('index.php')
       }
}
```

This is some `<a>` link that i have :

```
<a value="kerntaak1" onclick="protected_link();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg flex-item page-scroll"" style="letter-spacing: 5px";>kerntaak 1</a>
```

Comment: I assume you're getting it on line `var kerntaak = $(this).attr("id");`?

Comment: Presumably the problem is that `this` doesn't have the value you think it has, but we can't tell because we can't see how the function is being called … and you've edited it, so now we can.

Comment: `<a value="kerntaak1" ` — There is no `value` attribute for `<a>` elements.

Comment: @Quentin i have also try to use an ID as selector, but at the moment I copy my script it was <a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `protected_link(this.id);` with no context (which would be `foo.protected_link` or supplied via `.call()` or `.apply()`).

So inside the function `this` is going to be `window`.

Unsurprisingly `$(window).attr("id")` isn't going to give you the value you want.

You are passing the id as an argument:

```
protected_link(this.id);
               ^^^^^^^
```

… so use that.

```
function protected_link(kerntaak) { 
    alert(kerntaak);
```

Correction. You have edited the question. You **were** passing it as an argument. Then you deleted it. Undelete it. Put it back.

---

If you were writing modern JavaScript, you wouldn't be using intrinsic event attributes and you could do:

```
$("some selector that matches the elements you care about")
    .on("click", protected_link);
```

(I use jQuery to do the event binding because you are using it already)

That would be called in the context of the element and `this` would be the element inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now :) i used `onclick="protected_link(this.id);"` && `function protected_link(kerntaak) {`

Answer (score 2):

In `protected_link()`, `this` does not refer to the link the function was called from.

If, however, you change this:

```
<a value="kerntaak1" onclick="protected_link();" ...
```

To this:

```
<a value="kerntaak1" onclick="protected_link.call(this);" ...
```

`this` will refer to the `<a>` tag you want it to refer to.

[Learn more about function.call() in javascript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

PS: Quentin does a great job of explaining it.